# How to to remove "paypal/express/review" step on Magento2.4

Tags: magento2.4, paypal

When ordering using paypal in magento2, it takes you to paypal, paypal already displays a confirmation, you confirm, you get redirected to another confirmation page (/paypal/express/review), it is an extra step that is unnecessary for user experience, I would like to remove it and make the order automatically placed when user confirm on paypal page, once leave paypal if order successful the customer should see the success page.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Store -> Configuration-> Sales -> Payment Method -> Paypal -> Express Checkout -> Basic Settings - PayPal Express Checkout -> Advanced Settings -> Skip Order Review Step -> Yes**

select **"Skip Order Review Step" --> "Yes"**

Cheers !!

[image]

Comment: After SETTING according to your method, it doesn't work. I feel that there is no order confirmation page because I only go through the shopping cart process
What I want is to directly click paypal on the product details page, enter my paypal account, and click Continue. I need to jump to the order confirmation page. I don't want this confirmation page.